# Returning scope from Controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-decorator

I want to bind the return value (always an object) of a Controller to the scope.

instead of:

```
$scope.test = "test"
```

like so:

```
return {
  test: "test"
}
```

so i can use it in my view like

```
{{ test }}
```

The reason i want to use this is because of my directives, services, etc. still working like this.

```
(function(module) {

  var SomeFactory = function SomeFactory(

  ) {

    var test = 2;

    var getTest = function getTest() {
      return test;
    }

    return {
      getTest : getTest
    }
  }

  module.factory('someFactory', [
    SomeFactory
  ])

})(angular.module('app'))
```

So my controller should be look like this:

```
(function(module) {

  var SomeController = function SomeController(
    $state
  ) {

    var loggedIn = true;

    var isLoggedIn = function isLoggedIn() {
      return loggedIn;
    }

    return {
      isLoggedIn : isLoggedIn
    }
  }

  module.controller('SomeController', [
    '$state',
    SomeController
  ])

})(angular.module('app'))
```

Someone can help.

An alternative solution like:

```
$scope.add({
  test: 2,
  do: function() {}
})
```

is also okay :)

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
I want only returning an object {} and this object accessible over a decorator or something else

Comment: Sorry but what seems to be the problem? could you provide us with an example code that you have done? :)

Comment: There are example codes in the question. In my controller i want that the returning object is passed through the scope. So I must decorate the controller or decorate the scope, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your scope in the controller the following way:

```
angular
  .module("myModule", [])
  .controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
      angular.extend(
          $scope,
          {
              test: 2,
              do: function() { return 3;}
          }
      );
  }]);
```

and then use it like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  {{test}}
  {{do()}}
</div>
```

[Plunker with an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/n6xYB6qifOyJlj7Rc9Pd?p=preview)

Comment: Okay, thats a alternative solution. When no one has an other idea i will prefer this solution. But i really want to return an object. And the decorator or something else will take this returning object and pass it trough the scope, but i dont know how and on which method, place, etc. i must do that. I am only an intermediate in angular

Comment: angular.extend(
          $scope,
          {
              test: 2,
              do: function() { return 3;}
          }
      );

Comment: this line of code i want at every controller and in  the controller i only returning =>  {
              test: 2,
              do: function() { return 3;}
          }

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. You can only decorate controller and add method "add" to $scope. Please look at an example here http://plnkr.co/edit/oyWkMmMXKkzncd2kotl6?p=preview. But to be honest I don't like that approach.

Comment: In my opinion, that brings some unexpected behavior as no one expects that $scope is extended by additional methods. It is possible to spent hours in debugging to figure out what is going on.